# Magento 2.2.8 - Add Custom Attribute To Category

Tags: magento2, category, attributes

I need to add a wysiwyg attribute to the Magento categories, this needs to sit within the 'General Information' tab. I can't seem to get it to work and I've had a look around on StackOverflow and I can't see a complete answer.

This is what I have so far

```
<?php
namespace ModuleName\CategorySecondContent\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    public function __construct( CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $setup->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'bottom_content', [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Bottom Content',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();

    }
}
```

and then in the ui_compoment I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="category_custom_editor" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">10px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <scopeLabel>[STORE VIEW]</scopeLabel>
                <label translate="true">Custom Editor</label>
                <dataScope>category_custom_editor</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>4</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
```

Can anyone let me know where it's going wrong.

Comment: Is your code displayed in any other tabs?(Groups)

Comment: No it doesn't seem to be

Comment: can you see your category attribute in database table ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your xml code in

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

Comment: I've done this, but the category view will not show at all now, I just get a spinning wheel.

Comment: can you please update full code of your xml?

Answer (score 0):

Please Add Below code in File Path :ModuleName/CategorySecondContent/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">

        <field name="bottom_content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">bottom_content</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bottom Content</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string"></item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Also, run below Command and verify that module is enable?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> File: app/code/{{vendorName}}/{{ModuleName}}/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace {{vendorName}}\{{ModuleName}}\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

        $menu_att = [
            'bottom_content' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Bottom Content',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 90,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information'
            ]
        ];

        foreach($menu_att as $item => $data) {
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, $item, $data);
        }
        $idmenu =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
        foreach($menu_att as $item => $data) {
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idmenu,
                $item,
                $data['sort_order']
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> File:
>   app/code/{{vendorName}}/{{ModuleName}}/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="bottom_content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bottom Content</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope it helps!